# Galera cluster: change the size of InnoDB Redo log files online?

Tags: innodb, mariadb, galera, transaction-log

We have a 3 node Galera cluster. I need to change the mysqld `innodb_log_file_size` parameter (see [Changing the Number or Size of InnoDB Redo Log Files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-data-log-reconfiguration.html)).

I do this by stopping all 3 nodes and disabling Puppet. Can I do this change online with Galera? How?

```
> select VERSION();
+----------------------+
| VERSION()            |
+----------------------+
| 5.5.41-MariaDB-wsrep |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The InnoDB redo log files are independent of galera.  Because of this, you should be able to change the redo log configuration by doing a rolling restart and following the procedure in the link you referenced.